# Google map does not display properly and only shows grid

Tags: android, google-maps

My application's function about Google Maps doesn't work, the map only displays a grid instead of a map.

I have a map key, and the function is good previously. From logcat I can get the location.

Today, I had to make change in my code to fix a bug (not associated with the Google Maps code). The problem has started since then.

In my phone (HTC G8 os2.1) the Map Software is OK, but my application's doesn't show the map normally.

I haved tried to apply for a new Google Map key. Then I used this key make a demo.  The same issue occurs.

---

Today I observed something new:

When I make a demo for Google Maps, the demo has same problem.  Some previously installed demos run fine. Their map keys are same as my my current application's.

The problem persists even after uninstalling and installing these demos again.

Comment: This question gets asked every day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my mistake.

I shouldn't use the default ( C:\Documents and Settings\XXXXuser.android\debug.keystore ) . the "C:/first.keystore" is corresponds with my map API Key.

Should use "C:/first.keystore"

That's why the google server can't response any content. So my map only show grid!!!

Comment: what is first.keystore

Answer (score 2):

> In my phone (htc g8 os2.1) the Map Software is OK, But my application's map can't show normally.

Then your API key is bad, or your application lacks the `INTERNET` permission.

Comment: I'm so sorry . It's my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

step1 :  find the AVD's debug.keystore (windows--> perferences --> android --> build  "default debug keystore") . Then rename this file. (maybe debug11.keystore)

step2 : use cmd tool and get into C:\Documents and Setting \XXXXuser.android
        execute the command:
        keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.key store -alias androiddebugkey -keyalg RSA -validity 10000

step3 : then execute the command get MD5 fingerprint
        keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore

step4 : use this MD5 fingerprint get apikey from http://code.google.com/android/maps-api-signup.html

step5 : use the map api key.

Answer (score 0):

I misplaced my permission and screwed up the whole thing. Tried generating the MD5 for a few times and turn up the same. Apparently that line of permission in the Manifest causes this problem -.- . How silly.